# Drupal mail, how do I set the recipient address to Nice Name?

Tags: emails

Drupal mail is sending messages to

```
username <email@domain>
```

This looks like martin-green

I would like to specify the user name as "Martin Green ".

We have extended the user fields to include first and last names.

The email messages are constructed as follows:

```
  $result = drupal_mail(YogaHivePasses::MODULE_NAME, self::EMAIL_KEY, $userFromOrder->mail, $lang, $message);
```

There is a hook_mail

```
function yhivepasses_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch ($key) {
  case YogaHivePasses::EMAIL_KEY :
    $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
    $message['body'] = $params['body'];

    // May not be any parameters. Parameters are mainly used to send attachments.
    if (array_key_exists('params', $params)) {
    $message['params'] = $params['params'];
  }

  foreach ($params['headers'] as $key => $value) {
    $message['headers'][$key] = $value;
  }
  break;
default:
  return;
 }
}
```

The mimemail module is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format email sender right before calling drupal_mail()

```
  $name = 'Martin Green';
  $mail = 'email@domain.com';

  $from = '"' . addslashes($name) . '" <' . $mail . '>';

  $result = drupal_mail(YogaHivePasses::MODULE_NAME, self::EMAIL_KEY, $userFromOrder->mail, $lang, $message, $from);
```

or in hook_mail()

```
function yhivepasses_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch ($key) {
    case YogaHivePasses::EMAIL_KEY :
      // You can pass these variables to drupal_mail() or get them somehow.
      $name = 'Martin Green';
      $mail = 'email@domain.com';

      $message['from'] = '"' . addslashes($name) . '" <' . $mail . '>';

      $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
      $message['body'] = $params['body'];

      // May not be any parameters.
      // Parameters are mainly used to send attachments.
      if (array_key_exists('params', $params)) {
        $message['params'] = $params['params'];
      }

      foreach ($params['headers'] as $key => $value) {
        $message['headers'][$key] = $value;
      }

      break;

    default:
      return;
  }
}
```